# Finding a set of equally spaced perpendicular lines along boundaries in R

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I've got a dataframe in R that describes the individual counties of a state. My desired outcome is a set of perpendicular lines (don't need an actual linestring, just want to know the direction of the bisector at a point) at evenly spaced points along the boundaries of the counties.

There are a couple of extra considerations I have. One is that I don't what the outer boundary of the state to be included. Another is that I want these perpendiculars along the *unique* boundary, that is, if county A and county B share a border, I only want to sample bisectors from their shared border once.

Right now, I am using `st_boundary(st_combine(counties))` to get the unique boundary lines across the state.

To generate bisectors, I've tried two things with little luck. The first is sampling points along this line, connecting every consecutive pair into a line, and then finding the line perpendicular to all of those lines. The problem I've been having with this approach is that the randomly sampled points jump from county to county, so a line connecting one randomly sampled point to the next randomly sampled point doesn't necessarily reflect the actual boundaries of the counties.

My second idea was to use `st_segmentize()`, but I've been having trouble with that too. Namely, it seems to be having issues segmentizing the multilinestring that comes as a result of using `st_combine()` on the counties. I'm also having difficulty controlling the maximum length of a segment.

Any direction, comments, or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

My approach based on basic geometry:

A few boundaries instead of counties:

```r
bb <- osmdata::getbb("Oborniki Śląskie")
osmdata::set_overpass_url("https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter")
boundaries <- osmdata::opq(bb, timeout = 25 * 100) |>
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(key = "boundary", value = "administrative") |>
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(key = "admin_level", value = "8") |>
  osmdata::osmdata_sf() |>
  osmdata::unique_osmdata()

boundaries$osm_multipolygons |>
  sf::st_geometry() |>
  plot()
```

[image]

Let's take only two, find their common boundary and play with that boundary. You can use st_intersects() to find the pairs of counties with common boundaries.

```r
b <- boundaries$osm_multipolygons |>
  subset(name %in% c("Lubnów", "Jary")) |>
  subset(select = "geometry") |>
  sf::st_transform(crs = "EPSG:2180") |>
  sf::st_intersection()

plot(b$geometry, col = "gray")
```

[image]

As the product of intersection consist of 2 polygons and 1 multilinestring, we have to select only multilinestring. We will merge it to `LINESTRING` and select only geometry column.

```r
b <- b |>
  subset(sf::st_geometry_type(b) == "MULTILINESTRING") |>
  sf::st_line_merge() |>
  sf::st_geometry()

b |>
  plot(axes = TRUE)
```

[image]

Let's create few sample points on the boundary. For that we will use `st_line_sample()` function with density parameter. Please check help, if you wish to have N points (calculate the length of the linestring and space the poinst accordingly)

```r
sample_points <- sf::st_line_sample(b, density = 0.001, type = "regular") |>
  sf::st_cast(to = "POINT")
sample_points |>
  plot(add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Now we are converting the boundary (`LINESTRING`) to table of `POINTs` corresponding to nodes.

```r
points_from_boundary <- b |>
  sf::st_coordinates() |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = "EPSG:2180")
```

Let's focus on first sample point:

```r
p1 <- sample_points[1]
plot(p1, pch = 20, col = "red", add = TRUE)
```

And let's f find the closest point from our linestring points

```r
p2 <- points_from_boundary$geometry[sf::st_nearest_feature(sample_points[1], points_from_boundary)]
plot(p2, pch = 20, col = "blue", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Let's calculate the angle of the line between red and blue points:

```r
alpha <- 90 - 180 * atan(
  (sf::st_coordinates(p1)[2] - sf::st_coordinates(p2)[2]) / (sf::st_coordinates(p1)[1] - sf::st_coordinates(p2)[1])
) / pi
```

and let's create a dummy point P3, in distance of 200 m from P1, rotated perpendicularly to our alpha.

```r
y1 <- 200 * cos(90 + alpha)
x1 <- 200 * sin(90 + alpha)

p3 <- p1 + c(x1, y1)
sf::st_crs(p3) <- sf::st_crs(b)
plot(p3, pch = 20, col = "green", add = TRUE)

sf::st_cast(sf::st_union(p1, p3), "LINESTRING") |>
  plot(add = TRUE, col = "green")
```

[image]

The green line is perpendicular to boundary at first sample point. Now you have to wrap it to function and apply for all sample points and all your boundaries.

Regards,
Grzegorz